# Unable to Load Jenkins Shared Libraries

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have 2 scripts 1 is the scripted pipeline and 1 is the declarative pipeline

Scripted Pipeline (script1):

```
node ('Slave'){
stage('Loading app Deployment File') {
    def util = load './abcd/Jenkinsfile.groovy'
 }
}
```

Declarative Pipeline (script2)/(Jenkinsfile.groovy):

```
@Library('shared-library@master') _
import com.xaa.utils.myUtils
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ("Say Hello World") {
            steps {
                helloWolrd()
            }
        }
     }
```

from 1 script I am calling another, when declarative pipeline trying to load the shared Libraries  I am getting this error message

```
ERROR: Could not find any definition of libraries [shared-library@master]

org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: Loading libraries failed

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the library configuration in the Jenkins. Follow this official documentation https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

if it is due to the bug in the loading library as mentioned [in the link](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-60245) please use a dedicated stage to load the library.

```
pipeline {
 agent any
 stages {
   stage('init') {
      scripts {
        library "shared-library@master"
      }
   }
   stage('Build'){
     steps {
       echo "build stage"
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ram, No it's already configured (Manage Jenkins » Configure System » Global Pipeline Libraries )

Comment: Is there a chance that Jenkins can not fetch it? A typo or the repository is protected and requires a credentials

Comment: I don't see any typo errors, I am facing a similar kind of issue. https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-60245,

Comment: Got it. Can you add an additional stage as init? ‘stage(‘init){ steps { library “shared-library@master” } }

Comment: Thank you, Ram, should I add import com.xaa.utils.myUtils in the same step?

Comment: Best way is to use the fully qualified name when you use it instead of importing. Not a neat approach but a work around for this bug.

Comment: Mark it as an answer if it solved the issue for a better reach